# Storing a variable in ajax response as a global variable and use for sending other ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am getting ajax response as

```
{ pid: 6, status: true }
```

I need to store `pid` and pass it in the next ajax post request.

My current vue js is as follows

```
submitBox = new Vue({
  el: "#submitBox",
  data: {
    name: '',
    gstno: '',
    about: '',
    pid: '',
  },
  methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
      var vm = this;
      data = {};
      data['name'] = this.name;
      data['gstno'] = this.gstno;
      data['about'] = this.about;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'alpha/add/post/',
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(e) {
          if (e.status) {
            alert(" Success")

          } else {
            vm.response = e;

            alert(" Failed")
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  },
});
```

I need to store `pid` as a global variable and use the same for all the ajax requests. How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say 'store', do you mean storing the result somewhere outside `Vue`??

Comment: no inside the vue itself? and it is better if an able to use it in another vue too..

Comment: Oh... you'd better use `Vue components` and `Vuex` then, if the data you want to store will only be used by other `Vue`s.

Answer (score 2):

small thing, if you have small application and there is not much architecture or `js` is resides on that page only then you can use global variable

> using `vuex` for just this little thing is not suggestible (it will be good if he is already using it)

when you get back ajax response then you can set `id` globally

```
if (e.status) {
    window._postPid = e.pid; // assume `e` is response and e.pid is 6
}
else {
    // according to your need.
    // this is optional window._postPid = null;
}
```

now you can access it anywhere you want using

```
console.log(window._postPid); // 6
```

this is not preferred for large scale app. as we dont want to spoil global namespace or conflict variables.

but it will do what you want.